# Why subtracting months from a lubridate date gives inconsistent results?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to get back to date prior to some month in the past.

Following is example code where i go 9 months back and get the expected result.

```
lubridate::ymd(20191231) + months(-9)
```

"2019-03-31"

Following is example code where i want to go 6 months back but get unexpected result.

```
lubridate::ymd(20191231) + months(-6)
```

[1] NA

Please help how to fix this?

Comment: Because June has 30 days. Use `%m-% month(6)` instead of `+ months(-6)`